# Why are these two seemingly-similar MySQL queries returning radically different results?

Tags: mysql, clause

I want to pull a list of units that have an overall rating of less than 4. The first query returns 1760 rows with data that seems to check out when cross referenced. The second query returns only 434 rows. Why would this be? I don't fully understand the "Group By" and "Having" clauses, so I'm guessing it has something to do with those.

````
'''
SELECT u.unitid
,AVG(r.overall) AS AverageRating
, u.ratingcount

FROM reviews r

LEFT JOIN units u
ON u.unitid = r.unitid

-- only retrieve active, non-terminated units set to display
WHERE u.active = 1
AND u.display = 1
AND u.terminated = 0

GROUP BY u.unitid

HAVING AverageRating < 4
;
```
```
SELECT u.UnitID
, u.rating
, u.ratingcount

from units u

WHERE u.rating < 4

-- only retrieve active, non-terminated units set to display
and u.active = 1
and u.display = 1
and u.terminated = 0
;
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Your first query looks at *all* the records and calculates average rating by Unit ID, and then the `HAVING` clause limits the final result to records where the average rating by Unit ID is less than 4.

Your second query lists all records where the rating is less than 4, and that's all it does. It doesn't average anything.

Here are a couple passable tutorials I found with a quick Google:

- GROUP BY: https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/group_by.php
- GROUP BY and HAVING: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/group-by-having-clause-sql

`HAVING` filters aggregate values like `SUM`, `AVG`, `MIN`, `MAX`, etc. It's similar to `WHERE`, but `WHERE` only filters *non*-aggregated values. You can do this:

```
SELECT UnitId, AVG(Rating)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY UnitId
HAVING AVG(Rating) < 4 -- Good: HAVING is for filtering on aggregate values
```

But you can't do this (only difference from above is `WHERE` instead of `HAVING` in the last line):

```
SELECT UnitId, AVG(Rating)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY UnitId
WHERE AVG(Rating) < 4 -- Bad: WHERE is for the raw values, before they're aggregated
```

Keep at it. You'll get there :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ed!